# Java screencasts for Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java

I am an SQL guy interested in learning OOP and Java but most of the books I read or come across don't touch databases.

Are there any screencasts available that can teach me the Spring Framework and the Hibernate framework directly without getting too deep into Java?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it's advisable for someone to try and pick up Spring or Hibernate without knowing Java well.

The best recommendation I can think of is the [Spring MVC step by step example](http://static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/).  It doesn't use Hibernate, but it does access a database using JDBC.  Get that working and modify it to use Hibernate once you're feeling confident.

Answer (score 4):

There is really valuable screencasts for Hibernate, about 18th videos: http://www.youtube.com/user/patrickwashingtondc 
It's good start point

Answer (score 1):

Some may or may not like this recommendation but because of the similarity between C# and Java and Hibernate and NHibernate I would maybe recommend Stephen Bohlen's excellent screencast series Summer of NHibernate.

http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/